# How to convert valgrind output to XML?

Tags: perl, valgrind

Actually I know that there is Test::Valgrind::Parser::XML perl module. But I have no idea how to use it: If anyone can provide documentation it would be great.

Comment: On the CPAN page for it, there is a section SUPPORT that explicitly tells how one can access the documentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [valgrind docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.erropts) show that valgrind accepts a `--xml=yes` tag to output messages as XML.  The format of the XML is specified in the `docs/internals/xml-output-protocol4.txt` inside the [source code repository](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html).

With that, you can use any XML parser and do whatever you want with the data.